# how to work with arrays and objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got an array of cars and i'm looping through each car. I take input from the user using window.prompt() method. I take that value and filter it through my array of cars. I just want to know how I can restrict the car name the user selects to only those in the array

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qomu1fny/

```
 var CarsWorld = {

        cars : ['Honda','toyota','mercedes','jaguar'],

        init: function(){

            var getData = prompt('Which Car You Wanna Drive','');

            for(var i = 0 ; i < this.cars.length ; i++){

                $('.wrap').append(' ' + this.cars[i] + ' <br/> ');

            }

        },

    };

    CarsWorld.init();
```

Comment: Your question wording is a bit obtuse. What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       var getData = prompt('Which Car You Wanna Drive','');

        var foundCar = "";
        for(var i = 0 ; i < this.cars.length ; i++){
            $('.wrap').append(' ' + this.cars[i] + ' <br/> ');

            //check if this car in the array is the picked car
            if(this.cars[i] == getData){
               foundCar = getData;
            }
        }

        $('.wrap').append('you picked ' + foundCar);
```

Note that if the car isn't on the list then it won't output anything. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e5qh3pvw/

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to rephrase your question to something more understandable (currently under peer review). I understand you want to have a prompt that will restrict the choices of the user to the car models in your array.

Unfortunately, `window.prompt()` cannot achieve this, neither is there any synchronous (blocking) way to achieve it. You will need to use a modal dialog, and insert a regular html `select` element with your choices, or use a group of radio buttons.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kennasoft/orjLhtum/) that started getting bloated as I progressed. I used a few advanced techniques, just to engage your curiousity, since I suspect you are new to javascript.

**Javascript:**

```
var CarsWorld = {

    cars : ['Honda','toyota','mercedes','jaguar'],

    init: function(){

        var getData = 'none';

        for(var i = 0 ; i < this.cars.length ; i++){

            $('.wrap').append(' ' + this.cars[i] + ' <br/> ');

        }

        var prompter = new CarsWorld.PromptSelect('Which Car You Wanna Drive', function(selected){
            getData = selected;
            alert('You chose '+ getData +'! ');
            //other logic you want to apply on getData
        });
        prompter.show();
    }

};

CarsWorld.PromptSelect = function(message, callback) {
    self = this;

    this.init = function(){
        self.dropdown = '<select id="selectedCar">';
        $.each(CarsWorld.cars, function(index, car){
            self.dropdown += '<option>' + car + '</option>';
        });
        self.dropdown += '</select>';
        self.markup = [
            '<div class="prompt">',
            '<div class="title">CarsWorld Prompt</div>',
            '<div class="body">',
            '<label for="selectedCar">'+ message +':</label>' + this.dropdown + '</div>',
            '<div class="footer">',
            '<button class="btn-ok">Ok</button>',
            '<button class="btn-cancel">Cancel</button>',
            '</div>',
            '</div>'
        ].join('');
    };
    this.show = function(){
        $('.overlay').show();
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        self.init();
        $('body').append(self.markup);
        $('.prompt .btn-ok').on('click', function(){
            self.hide();
            callback($('#selectedCar').val());
            self.destroy();
        });
        $('.prompt .btn-cancel').on('click', function(){
            self.destroy();
        });
        return self;
    };
    this.hide = function(){
        $('.prompt').hide();
        $('.overlay').hide();
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
        return self;
    };
    this.destroy = function(){
        self.hide();
        return self;
    };
};

CarsWorld.init();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1> Please choose the car of your type </h1>

    <div class="wrap"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 990;
    background: #444;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.prompt {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

.prompt .title {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    height: 10%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.prompt .body {
    background: white;
    height: 60%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.prompt .footer {
    background: grey;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 10%;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
```